# Inkscape normal text in math mode always italic in pdf_tex export

Tags: equations, pdftex, text, italic, inkscape

I have the following equation in Inkscape:

`$u_{s, \text{komp}}^{q}$`

Unfortunately the text ("komp") is italic in the pdf after running the pdf_tex in
the Texmaker.

[image]

Is there a way to modify the equation so that "komp" appears non-italic
in the resulting pdf?

**EDIT**:
Running `$u_{s, \mathrm{komp}}^{q}$` gives me the following result

[image]

which looks much better than the first one. But I still don't know if "komp" is written as"normal" text now.

Comment: I dont know how inkscape works, but does it help to write `\mahrm` instead of `\text`?

Comment: yeah, I just tried this and it looks much better now. But using `mathrm`, is `komp` written as normal text or as non-italic "math"?

Comment: I leave that for @davidcarlisle to answer. But I think it used the upright version of the text font. (Try and look what is included)

Comment: When I try it I get normal text (upright) also with `\text`, i.e., I can't reproduce the problem. Maybe you have something in your LaTeX document that changes the font used with `\text`? My MWE was just `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\input{drawing.pdf_tex}
\end{document}`, maybe you can try that too?

Comment: @Marijn With `\text` it should inherit the style from the surrounding text, right? So maybe OP was in italic mode, or maybe inkscape just works differently.

Comment: @mickep yes, exactly, the problem could be that the surrounding text is causing this. That's why I asked Domi1908 to try the MWE in my comment, which does not have any surrounding text and works well on my system with `\text` in Inkscape.

Comment: `\mathrm{komp}` is correct here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$u_{s, \text{komp}}^{q}$

\end{document}
```

Produces the error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.5 $u_{s, \text
                {komp}}^{q}$
?
```

It is best to stop there but if you (or your editor) scrolls past the error, the output is as you show:

[image]

You should never ignore errors.

You could add `amsmath` to define `\text` but `\text` is not the right command here, this is a math identifier and should be set with `\mathrm`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$u_{s, \mathrm{komp}}^{q}$

\end{document}
```

[image]